# Maximum healthy daily amount of cardio?

Tags: cardio

I've recently taken a 2-month contract in a remote part of the country, and I'll be doing night shifts for all of it. I've had to do night shift work in the past, and I've found daily exercise was very beneficial, but it's the first time I'll be in an unknown place with next to no nightlife for such a long time. So I've been thinking that one way I'll cope, is by trying to do a lot more of exercise daily.

I'm currently doing a minimum of 45 minutes of stationary bike cardio daily, every once in a while going up to 1 hour. I was wondering, are there any accessible guidelines about how much higher it is safe to go up? I'm a healthy 26 year old male with a bodyweight of 65 kg, if it helps.

Comment: A daily hour of cardio is practically routine for a lot of people. :) I think you will be fine. Listen to your body and when it tells you that you need to take a break.

Comment: Safe? We can't answer that. Many multisport endurance athletes do multiple hours a day, every day. Even a "sedentary" sport such as golf, top golfers are spending a few hours in the gym, more hours on the range, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the answers!